# Error: No configuration set for [aws] s3_shard_formatter. This is a required configuration

Tags: flyte

I started seeing this error in flyte:
    No configuration set for [aws] s3_shard_formatter.  This is a required configuration.

What does it mean? AFAIK we set S3_SHARD_FORMATTER env variable in the image and also when registering the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It means the [configuration object](https://github.com/lyft/flytekit/blob/d4cfedc4c580f08bf904e6e474a0b948a4608737/flytekit/configuration/aws.py#L5) is not set.  There are multiple ways to set it.

1. You can add it to the config file like so

```
[aws]
s3_shard_formatter=s3://bucket-name/{}/
s3_shard_string_length=2
```

2. You can set the environment variable `FLYTE_AWS_S3_SHARD_FORMATTER` to the value in the config example in 1. (or whatever your bucket name/path is).

However, usually when you see this error, what's actually happening is that the configuration option for where to look for the configuration file itself, is not being set correctly.

If you can get yourself into a Python repl, take a look at the following.

```
from flytekit.configuration.internal import CONFIGURATION_PATH
CONFIGURATION_PATH.get()
```

That path should be a `/full/path/from/root`.  `cat` it too just to check that it's what you expect.

If that config option returns an empty string, then your registration step must be in error.  Confirm which file is being used during registration.